# Type 'GameViewController' does not conform to protocol 'FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am developing a mobile application and I added a Facebook login option.
However, I have the error:

> Type 'GameViewController' does not conform to protocol 'FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate'

I used this code:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: to conform a protcol you need to override all the non optional methods in the conforming viewcontroller or class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate's methods like this:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {
    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        <#code#>
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        <#code#>
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //
    }
}
```